# Combining list of list of string by columns in python

Tags: python, join

I have a situation here.

What I have is

```
s = [['A','C','E'],['B','D','F'],...]
```

I need to merge the string vertically, meaning  I need to get the result of

```
res = [['A','B',..], ['C','D',..],['E','F',..]].
```

How do I get it ?

Thank you

Comment: Show what you tried as properly formatted code in the question. Hint: "zip" function can help here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `zip` method in combination with `unpacking` *operator*.

```
res = [list(item) for item in zip(*s)]
```

Output

```
> res
[['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D'], ['E', 'F']]
```